# Using Python regular expressions substitution

Tags: python, regex, substitution

I need to write a program that will deidentify names in a medical record. How can I substitute names that COULD include prefixes, suffixes and first initials or first names, but don't HAVE to have all of the above every time. For example, I can get the program to deidentify Dr. S Smith, but not Dr. Smith.

Thank you!

Here's the program I have so far:

```
# This program removes names and email addresses occurring in a given input file and saves it in an output file.

import re
def deidentify():
    infilename = input("Give the input file name: ")
    outfilename = input("Give the output file name: ")

    infile = open(infilename,"r")
    text = infile.read()
    infile.close()

    # replace names
    nameRE = "(Ms\.|Mr\.|Dr\.|Prof\.) [A-Z](\.|[a-z]+) [A-Z][a-z]+" 
    deidentified_text = re.sub(nameRE,"**name**",text)



    outfile = open(outfilename,"w")
    print(deidentified_text, file=outfile)
    outfile.close()

deidentify()
```

Comment: I think it heavily depends on the format of the input text file. Is your data in plain text file?

Comment: what are the different possibilities that need de-identifying? With or without prefix? With or without initials? With or without first names? Last names only? are there other last names in your file that should not change?

Comment: Pyan: Yes, a txt file

Comment: Julien: all of the above. For example, a patient may be referred to the first time as Ms Alice Smith, but afterwords as simply Ms. Smith; a Dr. might be J. Doe, MD once, and Dr. Doe another time

Answer (score 0):

The `[A-Z](\.|[a-z]+)` term in

```
"(Ms\.|Mr\.|Dr\.|Prof\.) [A-Z](\.|[a-z]+) [A-Z][a-z]+"
```

is searching for a first name or initial.  You want this part to be optional, so use capture groups.

```
nameRe = "(Ms\.|Mr\.|Dr\.|Prof\.)( [A-Z](\.|[a-z]+))?( [A-Z][a-z]+)"
re.sub(nameRe, r"\1\4" ,text)
```

The `?` in

```
re.sub(nameRe, r"\1\4" ,text)
```

says "this part is optional, but still treat it as a capture group even if it's empty."

The `r"\1\4"` tells `re.sub` to use the first and fourth capture groups (basically, a capture group starts evey time you see a `(`).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to use capture groups.

Comment: And if I take **name** out of re.sub, what happens to my substitution?

Comment: A capture group is basically just a match you can easily reference later, often for use in substitution.  For example, if I want to replace "Hello Fred" with "Hello Jane", the problem is I can't just replace every word with "Jane", because then I'd get "Jane Jane".  So instead, I use capture groups.  My regex is "([a-z]+) ([a-z]+)".  The match inside the first set of parentheses is my first capture group, and inside the second parens is my second capture group.  Now, to get "Hello Jane", I replace with "\1 Jane" -- I use my first capture group, "Hello", a space, and the word "Jane".

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
((?:Ms\.|Mr\.|Dr\.|Prof\.|Mrs\.) (?:[A-Z](?:\.|(?:[a-z])+) )?[A-Z][a-z]+)
```

However, I'd recommend parsing this file into a Python data structure (dictionaries, objects, whatever), and then you can simply omit the names when you print results, not to mention all the other handy things you can do once your data are in a Python program (e.g., has this patient been with us for more than five years? what percentage of patients have a credit card number as payment information?).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was that the expression needed to account for spaces using \s. Once this was entered, the program worked.